# Stanford NLP: Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use Stanford NLP and encounter a `Error while loading a tagger model (probably missing model file)` error. I can't figure out what's wrong. I have installed the main jar using maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I tried to install the models file using maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.1</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
```

But the package kept getting higlighted:

[image]

So I downloaded a model file from [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html#getting-a-copy) and added it using File - Project Structure - Add Library - Compile - OK:

[image]

However when I run a test class, it doesn't work and the aforementioned error arises:

```
package com.util;

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.CoreDocument;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;

import java.util.Properties;

public class TextEater {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        // set the list of annotators to run
        props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse,depparse,coref,kbp,quote");
        // set a property for an annotator, in this case the coref annotator is being set to use the neural algorithm
        props.setProperty("coref.algorithm", "neural");
        // build pipeline
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        // create a document object
        CoreDocument document = new CoreDocument("Hello how are you");
        // annnotate the document
        pipeline.annotate(document);
        // examples

        // 10th token of the document
        CoreLabel token = document.tokens().get(10);
        System.out.println("Example: token");
        System.out.println(token);
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Why doesn't manual importing of the models library seem to work? What can be done to fix it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: With the Maven managed project dependencies added manually (instead of pom.xml) will have no effect in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have to add the model with maven then... But the error doesn't let me.

Comment: You could delete the .idea folder of the project and before execute mvn clean install to download all dependencies, after success compilation you could open the project again. I think it help you.